# Add custom property to existing object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object which looks like this :

```
{ dateCreated: Fri Mar 18 2016 16:36:12 GMT+0400 (MUT),
 lastUpdated: Fri Mar 18 2016 16:36:12 GMT+0400 (MUT),
 users: [ '56ebdaad275a88df234a4480' ],
  viewOnlyUsers: [],
 __v: 0,
  owner: '56ebdaad275a88df234a4480',
 editUrl: 'e7f25e3d-be77-4cfa-a928-6af05f06ec44',
 viewUrl: '2669ba21-0e3b-4ac0-a886-74e3fe217af4?view',
 _id: '20c84dde-56b7-43ba-9fd3-510c1d24ba0f' }
```

How do i add a custom property to this object in Javascript?

I've tried

```
 workspaces[test] = 'test';
```

But it does not work.

Comment: If `test` is not variable, `workspace['test'] = 'test';` or `workspace.test = 'test';`

Comment: `workspaces['test'] = 'test';` or  `workspaces.test = 'test';`

Comment: what is `workspaces` and what is `test`?

Comment: Sorry folks. I messed up with the question. The part ' in an array is not needed'

Comment: If its an array of objects you would modify it as such `myArray[index][property] = 'value'` or myArray[index].myProp = 'value'

Comment: You have two typos in your code:
1) missing `'` before and after `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` values,
2) if `test` is not a variable, missing `'` before and after `test` in `workspaces[test]`

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes to the property name: `workspaces['test'] = 'test';`

However, this is fine too:

```
var test = 'myProp';
var workspaces = {}; // your object
workspaces[test] = 'test';
```